# Error retrieving a collection from Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have a collection of users and every user have a collection of properties called portfolio,
I am able to read the data but once im trying to make a copy of the document im facing an error "Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'FirestoreSource' that does not accept a closure".

```
    private func getPortfolioItems() {    
        if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
            let userID = currentUser.uid
            print("User ID: \(userID)")
            
            
            // assuming you have a reference to the Firestore database
            
            // assuming you have the user's ID stored in a variable called "userID"
            let userRef = db.collection("users").document(userID)
            
            // access the "portfolio" subcollection for the user
            let portfolioCollection = userRef.collection("portfolio")
            
            // create an empty array to store the posrtfolio properties
            var portfolioArray = [Property]()
        
//this is where im getting the error
            portfolioCollection.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                } else {
                    for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                        let dictionary =  document.data()
                        //print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                        print(dictionary["property_address"]!)
                        myDic.append(dictionary)
                        print(myDic.count)
            
                    }
                }
                myDic.forEach({ (dictionary) in
                    print(dictionary)
// this is what causing the error, when i try to create an instance of property
                    let property = Property(address:dictionary["property_address"],
                                           bath: dictionary["property_baths"],
                                           room: dictionary["property_beds"],
                                           size: dictionary["property_price"],
                                           price: dictionary["property_size"])

                })
                
            }
    }
```

I have tried to make the of the document out side the scope and i faced an error "Value of type 'Any' has no subscripts"

Comment: It's not clear what line causes the error neither what you are trying to do since the function getPortfolioItems neither returns anything nor sets/updates any property.

Comment: Hi i add comments where im getting the error and what causing it, the function should create an instance of property with the value im retrieving from firebase, theb create an array and add all properties to the array and return it. Ignore the array part ill add it once Im able to create an instance

Comment: `portfolioCollection.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err in`, I see a left parentheses but no corresponding right one in this line.